# Чтение XML в DataSet потоком

Tags: c#, xml

Возможно ли считать XML файл в `DataSet` с помощью потока? Например, если XML большой по объему? Если применять `ReadXml`, то пишет, что не хватает памяти.

Comment: Вроде был там такой класс XMLReader, он читал XML как поток.

Answer (score 0):

Чтение большого XML в DataSet при помощи XmlReader не решит проблему нехватки памяти.

Что можно сделать:

1. Собирайте приложение как 64bit - это увеличит оперативную память доступную приложению до 8TB.
2. Подумайте, можно ли избежать такой загрузки?
3. Не используйте DataSet. Можно от него отказаться в пользу, например, простых List.
4. Поставьте больше памяти.